# Xamarin build is very very slow after reconnecting device to USB

Tags: xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android, usb

I have an issue with building Xamarin Forms 3.0 (but happened on 2.5 as well) and debugging on a real device, using VS 2017 (latest 15.7, but same was on earlier versions). When device is plugged to USB i usuallly need to rebuild (clean + build, or just rebuild) the solutiuon. If not a deployment error occurs. This would not be a problem, but such rebuild after plugging device (or reconnecting after disconnecting for several seconds) takes AGES (!!) - at least 5 mnutes if not 10 in some cases. After this long build and succesful deploymetnt I can normally work, debug, and in this case building, deploying, starting the app - takes only several seconds. But when I unplug the device it all starts again and the build after reconnect takes AGES. It happens on 2 different laptops (both with newest Windows 10, Visual Studio etc). I use Android 8.1 (but same happened on previous versions)

Any suggestions ? Thi is very annoying

EDIT:
As requested in comments - the screen of configuration
[image]

Comment: What are your "Android Options" in your Android project properties? I mean [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/de-de/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing/preparing-an-app-for-release/#Set_Packaging_Properties)

Comment: For a faster debugging experience try enable `Use Fast Deployment` and `AOT Compilation` and also disable `Use LLVM Optimizing Compiler`.

Comment: @Vahid I edited my post with screen of project config

Comment: OK, what about other mentioned properties? I.e AOT and LVVM.

Comment: Especially LVVM which enabling it will hugely decrease deploy time.

Comment: I guess this option is missing in my adroid options

Comment: I guess AOT and LLVM options are available only in Enterprise edition of Visual Studio.
In that case you have too look for another options. As I experienced deploying on some low-end mobile devices with low specs would generally take longer deploy time. Try to debug on another device with higher specs.